# What is the local stateless bean good for?

Tags: ejb, javabeans

Is there any reason to use Local Stateless beans in a Java EE application?
The interface of the bean is available via the factory design pattern.

Comment: Just because something's _available_ it doesn't mean it's _useful_. If you have no use for something, you don't need to use it.

Comment: Thread-local stateless beans might be useful if their implementation is not thread-safe. Request-local stateless beans might be useful if they are not really stateless but should be.

Answer (score 0):

Acrually, local stateless beans are the most common and popular bean types in Java EE.

Years ago the thinking was that everything should be remote, but we're way passed that now.

Stateful EJB beans were originally mainly for remote Swing-like clients (including applets). For web apps that already have an HTTP session their use is much less.

Local stateless EJB beans are perfect for typical Service and DAO code.